# How to invert the case of characters of the whole sentence?

Tags: java, regex

I can not explain how to invert the case of characters with the help of a regular. At this stage, changes the case of all characters, but it is necessary that I would change case only in the selection. What needs to be changed ??

**The task**
Create a class that displays the contents of a text file in the console, inverting the case of all characters of each word that contains more than 3 characters.

> ***In the file part1.txt lies***
>   When I was younger
>   So much younger
>   Than today
>   Информацию из файла
>   в верхний регистр

**part1.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Part1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(mainMethod(Util.readFile("part1.txt")));
    }

    public static String mainMethod(String input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{4,}+|[А-Яа-яёЁ]{4,}+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            char c = chars[i];
            if (m.find(0)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(c) || chars.length <= 4) {
                    chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
                } else {
                    chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                }
            }
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }
}
```

**Util.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Util {

    private static final String ENCODING = "Cp1251";


    public static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(bytes, ENCODING);
    }

    public static Matcher getMatcher(String regex, String input) {
        return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close as your regex is fine and you need to loop though chars of found match though few issues as follows:

• You need to loop though the found match instead of char array `input.toCharArray()`

• Get the match group using `matcher.group(1)`

so follow the steps to fix the issue:

1. Use `while (m.find())` to find all the matches
2. Convert the found match to `char` array using `m.group(1)` as

   ```
   char[] chars = m.group(1).toCharArray();
   ```
3. No need `||` (OR) condition for length and use [appendReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String))

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/jpG4Zq)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(mainMethod("When I was younger So much younger Than "+
    "today Информацию из файла в верхний регистр"));
}

public static String mainMethod(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{4,}+|[А-Яа-яёЁ]{4,}+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input.length());
    while (m.find()) {
        char[] chars = m.group(1).toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            char c = chars[i];
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
            } else {
                chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            }
        }
        m.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(chars));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everything was perfectly explained, have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks and I am glad that I could help. you too have a nice day, Happy coding!